# want specific word of list from given string

Tags: php, regex

I want specific word of list from given string, word which is starting with @xxx using php and regular expression.

e.g:

Volvo Trucks - Rajnikanth - The Epic Split feat. (Live Test 6) @xyz Thalaivar Epic Split Rajanikanth Rajinikanth Rajani Auto Auto rikshaw  and also @xyz.abc http://another.net  @bac.def this is tesging @pqr

I want return value like @xyz, @xyz.abc, @bac.def, @pqr this words from above string.

And I dont know about regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$input_lines="Volvo Trucks - Rajnikanth - The Epic Split feat. (Live Test 6) @xyz Thalaivar Epic Split Rajanikanth Rajinikanth Rajani Auto Auto rikshaw and also @xyz.abc http://another.net @bac.def this is tesging @pqr";
preg_match_all("/(@\w+[^\s+]+)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array[1]);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/110234)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @xyz
    [1] => @xyz.abc
    [2] => @bac.def
    [3] => @pqr
)
```

Comment: **+1** , Perfect. as the OP wanted.

Comment: You are genius.
It is exactly what i am finding.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution... Not a regex way though..

```
<?php
$str='Volvo Trucks - Rajnikanth - The Epic Split feat. (Live Test 6) @xyz Thalaivar Epic Split Rajanikanth Rajinikanth Rajani Auto Auto rikshaw and also @xyz.abc http://another.net @bac.def this is tesging @pqr';
$newarr[]=array_map(function ($v){ return $v='@'.explode(' ',$v)[0];},explode('@',$str));unset($newarr[0][0]);
print_r($newarr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => @xyz
    [1] => @xyz.abc
    [2] => @bac.def
    [3] => @pqr
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But i want it without foreach loop.

Comment: @user3378449, Removed `foreach` and used `array` functions.